# How to specify weight for call with loop

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, weight, fee, weighttofee

I have a loop in call which depends on array from arguments, so how can i specify weight to be multiplied to array length from arguments

Comment: Please ensure the quality of this StackExchange by including code examples and explaining your problem in detail such that others can profit from it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linear component if your call accepts a collection.
As example take this one:

```rust
pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, data: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult
{
    // Loop over data.
    Ok(())
}
```

Which can then be benchmarked by defining a linear component over the length of the input vector.

```rust
benchmarks! {
    do_something {
        // Define linear component l. Must have one letter as name.
        let l in 0 .. T::MaxDataLen::get() as u32;

        let data = vec![255u8; l as usize];
    }: _(RawOrigin::Root, data)
    verify { /*optional*/ }
}
```

It is important that your function has at most a linear complexity over each component, otherwise the weight formulas will be calculated incorrectly.

Finally you can use the newly generated weight function as such:

```rust
#[pallet::weight(
    T::WeightInfo::do_something(data.len() as u32)
)]
pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, data: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult
{
    // Loop over data.
    Ok(())
}
```

You can see how the weight now depends on the vectors length.